# GitHub Actions Workflow keeps running waiting for Authorization from Spotify

Tags: python, github-actions, spotify, spotipy

```
import os
import spotipy, tweepy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

# Spotify Part :

spotify_client_id = os.environ["SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID"]
spotify_client_secret = os.environ["SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET"]

sp = spotipy.Spotify(
    auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(
        scope="user-read-recently-played",
        client_id=spotify_client_id,
        client_secret=spotify_client_secret,
        redirect_uri="http://127.0.0.1:8080/callback",
    )
)
```

This is a part of my program in which there is Spotify API authorization but the GitHub Action Workflow keeps running as **redirect_uri** expect user to authorize it manually.

I've changed the **redirect_uri** to http://localhost:8080 but still it keeps running.
It works fine on my local machine as I can authorize it. But I'm unable to find any way to run it in GitHub action workflow.

Is there any 1 time authorization using the API credentials only which also provide recently played tracks on spotify.

I tried changing URI but not working.
I am expecting a way to get Spotify recently played tracks using API credentials only.

The repo with action : https://github.com/AzeemIdrisi/TweetifyMusic

Comment: Just looked at the Actions tab of that repo. Looks like the CI workflow is completing successfully. Are you still facing issues with this? If not, you may self-answer this how you fixed it or delete this question. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I just fixed it with the help of ChatGPT, Earlier I was not using refresh_token to get access_token. Using refresh_token we do not need to manually authorize it everytime. @Azeem Thanks for looking into it.